# Redgate Schema Compare

Tags: sql-server, redgate

Our constraint names are typically left to SQL to auto generate so, when comparing databases, they always come up as a difference. I've selected "ignore constraint and index names" but they are still displayed as a difference.

[image]

What I need to do to stop the false positives being reported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using system named constraints, so you should check the last check box: "Ignore system named constraints and index names".

Comment: awesome! that did it. Thanks.